# multiple models of the same length iterating simultaneously

Tags: java, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I have a very particular question related to thymeleaf in spring boot, using the Java Persitence API (JPA).

I have three tables (A, B, C), hence models, they look like this:

A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class ATable {
  private int aid;
  private String acontent;

  // getters and setters

}
```

B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class BTable {
  private int bid;
  private String bcontent;

  // getters and setters
}
```

C:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class CTable {
  private int cid;
  private String ccontent;

  // getters and setters
}
```

These three tables, by design, will have the same amount of content.

The rows of the tables are like this:

A:

aid  acontent

1    a1
2    a2
3    a3

B:

bid  bcontent

1    b1
2    b2
3    b3

C:

cid  ccontent

1    c1
2    c2
3    c3

Now, I would like to iterate through these three tables simultaneously in my HTML5 template, the result should be something like this:

a1
b1
c1

---

b1
b2
b3

---

c1
c2
c3

---

My controller is like this:

```
...

List<ATable> atable = new ArrayList<>();
model.addAttribute("atable", atable);

List<ATable> atables = atableRepository.findAll();
model.addAttribute("atables", atables);


List<BTable> btable = new ArrayList<>();
model.addAttribute("btable", btable);

List<BTable> btables = btableRepository.findAll();
model.addAttribute("btables", btables);


List<CTable> ctable = new ArrayList<>();
model.addAttribute("ctable", ctable);

List<CTable> ctables = ctableRepository.findAll();
model.addAttribute("ctables", ctables);

...
```

To iterate through only one of these tables I could something like this:

```
<tr th:each="atable : ${atables}">

<span th:text="${atable.acontent}">

</tr>
```

But how can we do it simultaneously with, say, three tables?

I think I have been clear enough with tables representing my issue, and I really hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DTO that represents a row in your HTML:

```
public class Row {
  private ATable atable;
  private BTable btable;
  private CTable ctable;

  // constructor + getters here
}
```

Then use this in your controller:

```
@GetMapping
public String showPage(Model model) {
  List<ATable> atables = atableRepository.findAll();
  List<BTable> btables = btableRepository.findAll();
  List<CTable> ctables = ctableRepository.findAll();

  List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
  for( int i = 0; i < atables.size();i++) {
    rows.add(new Row(atables.get(i), btables.get(i), ctables.get(i));
  }
  
  model.addAttribute("rows", rows);
}
```

Now iterate in Thymeleaf through your rows:

```
<tr th:each="row : ${rows}">

  <span th:text="${row.atable.acontent}">
  <span th:text="${row.btable.acontent}">
  <span th:text="${row.ctable.acontent}">

</tr>
```