# Grabbing Element in Twos from a List in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

i have a list that contains entity classes with two variables (id and categoryname). My entity looks like this:

```
String categoryName;
int categoryID;

//getters and setters
```

My controller class returns a List of all categories using

```
service.findAll();
```

Normally an iteration over this kind of list is one element at a time. My question is I want to be able to get two elements at a tome from the list to enable me populate the UI, which has two columns. Or in more simpler terms, how can I iterate over two elements at once in a List?

```
<div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-3">
                    <div>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="category" th:value="${category.id}"> <label th:text="${category.categoryName}">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="category" th:value="${category.id}"> <label th:text="${category.categoryName}">
                    </div>
                      
                  </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963712/multiple-models-of-the-same-length-iterating-simultaneously or something else ?

Comment: No. What I mean is that I want to get two entities in the list at a time, as I am working on a 2 column interface. The checkboxes are displayed in a 2 column. So I want to get two entities at once from the List instead of just 1, which is the default when loops happen.

Comment: Your question remains unclear to me. Maybe you can edit it and provide some more details on how those entities look like, how you want the iteration to look like, how your controller looks like, etc...

Comment: I just edited it now. I hope its a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work:

```html
<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, list.size()-1, 2)}">
//Edit: I added -1 to list.size()
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-3">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="category" th:value="${list[i].id}">
      <label th:text="${list[i].categoryName}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="category" th:value="${list[i+1].id}"> 
      <label th:text="${list[i+1].categoryName}">
    </div>                   
  </div>
</th:block>
```

You will have to do something if the size of the list is not a multiple of 2, unless you know for sure this will always be the case.

PS: I wonder if maybe it is better to use a normal iteration and use CSS to choose how many columns you show depending on screen width for example.

Comment: Thank you. It worked well. I am quite terrible at UI and don't understand html/css very much. I do not know how that will work. The two divs holding the checkboxes are the two columns  am trying to populate. I don't know how your suggestion fits. Thank you